# In PHP, how can i get fopen to timeout very fast when opening a local file?

Tags: php, timeout, fopen, local-files

I'm having a problem with PHP where i'm writing to a file very often, and sometimes it takes a long time to open that file.
The complete description is here:

[fopen file locking in PHP (reader/writer type of situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759345/fopen-file-locking-in-php-reader-writer-type-of-situation)

My question is how can I get fopen to timeout in, say, 50ms.
I looked at [stream-context-create](http://docs.php.net/function.stream-context-create) but that seems to be for HTTP, or at least, if it'll work for local files, I'm not sure how to specify the option in the array.

Any ideas?

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: Artefacto's answer is valid - however PHP does not have sophisticated file handling semantics, nor the low-level OS access erquired to implement them. If it's at all possible, don't use files for storing your data in PHP

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying here, but in some platforms (not Windows, though), you can open a file in non-blocking mode with the `n` flag:

```
$f = fopen("/tmp/foo/bar", "wn+");
```

This should return immediately. You can then probably use [`stream_select`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) with a timeout of 50 ms.

I say "probably" because this flag is not documented.

Answer (score -1):

changing the `default_socket_timeout` variable in the **php.ini** to `'1'`, would that helps?